# MySQL to SQL 2008 query conversion, only 1 field returned with data. Multiple left joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server-2008

I have a pretty large database from an ERP system running SQL Server 2008 that I have to access. When developing, we were on a MySQL staging server (why they decided to setup a test environment with a different database engine is beyond me, I am just stuck with the aftermath). Here is the query after removing all of the ` and setting it up to be a ?valid? SQL 2008 query:

```
SELECT OrderHed.OrderNum AS order_no,
OrderHed.Character02 AS contact, OrderHed.Character03 AS address1,
OrderHed.Character04 AS address2, OrderHed.Character05 AS address3, OrderHed.Character06 AS city,
OrderHed.ShortChar02 AS state, OrderHed.ShortChar03 AS zip, OrderRel.Plant AS shipping_origin,
OrderDtl.OrderLine AS order_line, OrderDtl.SellingQuantity AS line_item_qty,
Part.NetWeight AS line_item_weight, UD02.ShortChar02 AS line_item_class,
Part.PartDescription AS line_item_description, OrderDtl.PartNum AS line_item_sku,
OrderDtl.KitFlag AS line_item_kit_flag, Part.ShortChar04 AS line_item_upsable,
UD02.Key1 AS line_item_box_code
FROM OrderHed 
LEFT JOIN OrderDtl ON OrderHed.OrderNum = OrderDtl.OrderNum
LEFT JOIN Part ON OrderDtl.PartNum = Part.PartNum
LEFT JOIN UD02 ON Part.ShortChar03 = UD02.Key1
LEFT JOIN OrderRel ON OrderRel.OrderLine = OrderDtl.OrderLine 
AND OrderRel.OrderNum = OrderHed.OrderNum 
WHERE OrderHed.OrderNum = 99 AND 
OrderDtl.KitFlag <> 'C' AND 
OrderRel.Plant LIKE '%'
```

This query returns a row for each line item, but everything is NULL except order_no. Notice we are joining 4 tables, OrderHed contains things like order number, shipping address, etc. OrderDtl contains an entry for each item in an order (one entry per order per sku, with quantity). Part & UD02 contain item information (looked up by SKU). Even bigger problem is the fact that the natural column names are duplicated across the tables, leaving me to explicitly name them (which works out better on the receiving end anyways since their column names are not sensible).

Note: `SELECT * FROM OrderHed ...LEFT JOIN ...LEFT JOIN ...` seems to return a row for each item in an order like it should; however, the only columns that are not NULL are the ones in the OrderHed table. Any ideas? The query produces no errors and In MySQL this works. The only difference is the MySQL query has a `GROUP BY OrderHed.OrderNum`

Another note: Using PHP to connect, with the php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll Microsoft ODBC Driver for PHP. Other queries seem to be working just fine.

Need more info? Just ask...I will provide, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are testing columns from LEFT JOINed tables in the WHERE clause, which will force those joins to behave like INNER JOINs. Instead, make those tests part of the join conditions.

```
SELECT ...
FROM OrderHed 
LEFT JOIN OrderDtl ON OrderHed.OrderNum = OrderDtl.OrderNum
    AND OrderDtl.KitFlag <> 'C' 
LEFT JOIN Part ON OrderDtl.PartNum = Part.PartNum
LEFT JOIN UD02 ON Part.ShortChar03 = UD02.Key1
LEFT JOIN OrderRel ON OrderRel.OrderLine = OrderDtl.OrderLine 
    AND OrderRel.OrderNum = OrderHed.OrderNum 
    AND OrderRel.Plant LIKE '%'
WHERE OrderHed.OrderNum = 99
```

Comment: This has the same results as the first query, one row per item, the only thing that is filled in for each for is `order_no`, no errors.